# how to avoid form from submitting if both these values are valid

Tags: jquery, json, cfc

Hi Below is the code that i am using for my form to validate id's entered in two input fields.All code is working fine.Only thing is that how to stop form from submitting if both the fields are not valid as i am disabling and enabling submit button if record return is true.but if any one field is valid then submit button is enabling and allowing user to submit form.

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="1" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="2" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"  id="submitbutton" >
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $$(document).ready(function() {             
            $$('#1').blur(function() {              
            var id = $$('#1').val();             
            $$.getJSON("user.cfc?method=getRequests&returnformat=json&queryFormat=column",{"status":id}, function(res1,code) {

                if(res1.ROWCOUNT > 0){  

                  for(var i=0; i<res1.ROWCOUNT; i++) {                      
                    s = "<span class='dPostTxt'>" + res1.DATA.ID[i] + " " + res1.DATA.FIRST_NAME[i] + " " + res1.DATA.LAST_NAME[i] + " " + "is valid." + "</span>";
                  };                  
                 $$('#submitbutton').removeAttr('disabled');//now id is valid so enabling submit button                  
                } 
                else {
                  $$('#submitbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //error with id so disabling button 
                  alert(" ID Is Not Valid.Please Enter Valid ID");
                  var s = "Entered  ID Is Not Valid.";                                  
                }     

                $$("#results").html(s);                
                },"json");                  
           });  }); 
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $$(document).ready(function() {              
            $$('#2').blur(function() {              
            var id = $$('#2').val();             
            $$.getJSON("user.cfc?method=getRequests&returnformat=json&queryFormat=column",{"status":id}, function(res,code) {

                if(res.ROWCOUNT > 0){  

                  for(var i=0; i<res.ROWCOUNT; i++) {                   
                    s = "<span class='dPostTxt'>" + res.DATA.ID[i] + " " + res.DATA.FIRST_NAME[i] + " " + res.DATA.LAST_NAME[i] + " " + "is valid." + "</span>";
                  };
                 $$('#submitbutton').removeAttr('disabled');//now id is valid so enabling submit button                  
                } 
                else {                  
                  $$('#submitbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //error with id so disabling button 
                  alert(" ID Is Not Valid.Please Enter Valid ID");
                  var s = "Entered  ID Is Not Valid.";                                  
                }     

                $$("#results1").html(s);                
                },"json");                  
           });  }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Whats with all the double dollar signs? (`$$`??)

Comment: usually a result of shoehorining jQuery into a page that already has something assigned to $

Comment: why two `<script>` blocks, why two `$$`... what is this, noah's ark? :)

Comment: Sidenote: You can't use numbers as `id`s

Comment: Also wouldn't the second `$$(document).ready(function() {` overwrite the first one anyways? I don't think that having two of them would work out to well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form").submit(function() { 
    bool valid = goValidateForm();
    if(!valid)
        return false; //prevents form from submitting
    else
        goDoSomeCoolStuff();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

assign your checks to fire on `$("form").submit()` instead of onBlur of the fields. that way you can check both states at the same time, maybe fire a alert to the page if your form values are wrong &etc.

Comment: $$ is for i made var $$ = jQuery.noConflict(); which is working fine code i working fine only thing is to top form from submitting if any o value is error validation